# React Native - How to change scroll speed on onScroll event

Tags: react-native

I want `ScrollView` to scroll more fast because it take 1sec time to scroll end even if it scroll little distance.

Does `ScrollView` have a option of change scroll speed?
or Do I have a another way?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, but the [office doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) does not support changing scroll speed of `ScrollView` component. if you need, you can try to write a new native scrollView.