# How to autoplay a React Native ScrollView?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a `ScrollView` to autoplay itself and have tried the below implementation:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._interval = setInterval(() => {
        this._scrollViewX+=1;
        this._scrollView.scrollTo({x: this._scrollViewX, y: 0, animated: true}) },
      800
    );
  }
```

Render():

```
           <ScrollView
            ref={(c) => {this._scrollView = c;}} 
            horizontal={true}>

            <View style={{paddingTop: '3%', flex: 1, width: 900,  flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
              {this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <View 
                    style={{margin:4, marginHorizontal:12}}
                    key={index}>
                    <TextItemToggle
                      value={item}
                      onPress={(value)=>{this._onPressHandler(value)}}
                    />
                  </View>
                )
              })}
            </View>

          </ScrollView>
```

I have also tried an increment of `0.1` with `16`ms interval. They all seemed a bit laggy. Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: 0.1 and 16 are the pixels no? You need more than that to see it scrolling (think of width 900 that you put)

Comment: I intend to make it slow. 0.1 increment and 16 interval actually gives pretty good speed of scrolling. The problem is that its not smooth enough, like you can tell the "scrolling" is being paused every 16ms...

Answer (score 0):

You do it on ComponenDidMount() which will take into consideration the whole component life cycle to update screen. [I am sure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39481584/5890227) you [can not control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36055094/5890227) the speed of scrolling. You either `animated:true` or `false` and that's it.